# How to get opt-in URL for internal-test?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I would like to test my app by sending an **`opt-in URL`** to testers through the **`internal test`** feature. I created the release and waited for the review to complete. The app status now states: **`unpublished`** and **`all updates are live`** (Google has me heavily confused what that means exactly). Where I expect the URL to show it states: **`an opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app`**. And on the store-presence tab it states: **`your app is currently unavailable on the play store`** (which makes sense as I don’t want it to). Under that is a **`Publish`** button...

What should I do to get the opt-in URL? Should I keep waiting (other questions indicate it should appear automatically but it could take several days?). If I select to **`Publish`** wouldn’t it be published on the Play Store? (which I do **not** want).

(As it may matter, note that I **did** have an earlier version of the app being public on the app-store. As that was by mistake (another confusion on the Play Console workings caused me to select `**release to production**`), I selected **`unpublish`** at the time to fix that).

Answer (score 1):

Heres how you can get your opt-in URL:
Navigate to the Release Management >> App Releases Then Internal Test Track, Click on the "Manage" Button which takes you to the Internal Test page, click on the Manage Testers Dropdown button then scroll down, There you will find your Opt-in URL
[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

Comment: No, sorry. This is where it states: **`an opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app`**. (See question)

Comment: @HansBouwmeester There is an update in the policy (which might not be mentioned yet), so you can try it uploading in Alpha version and at last need to wait for at least 24-48 hours for app to be published for testing. As per the new norms of Google Play.

Comment: There is no Release management anymore on the console :(

Answer (score 0):

In the new console, you have it under internal testing / testers tab, at the bottom of the page:

[image: feedback url]